# Why doesn't this PHP if statement work?

Tags: php

I have a parameter in the url for birthday `?user_birth_day=05`, and I have the following codes:

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['user_birth_day']; ?> // this outputs 5

<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) : ?>                     
    <?php if($_REQUEST['user_birth_day'] === $i){ echo 'BINGO'; } ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

The if statement simply prints nothing. Please help!

Comment: `if((int) $_REQUEST['user_birth_day'] === $i)` or `if($_REQUEST['user_birth_day'] == $i)`

Comment: you should read this page about difference between operator `==` and `===` http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Side note: You don't have to enclose each and every line with `<?php ... ?>`. This is for contiguous blocks of PHP code, not just for single lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you make a strict equality comparison (`===`) which will check types too and the value in `$_REQUEST` is a string, not a number. You might need to make the check less strict by using `==`.

Keep in mind that values you get from `GET` or `POST` requests are always strings since HTTP doesn't have any means of attaching types. What I have seen sometimes is to convert incoming data into appropriate types as part of input checking, e.g. if you expect a field to contain a number, then check if it is and convert it to a number, otherwise abort. But there are probably plenty of ways to solve that.

As a rough debugging technique (if you don't have access to an actual debugger or are as stupid as me and can't get xdebug to work properly in Eclipse) you can use `print_r` on values you want to examine and thus also learn their types (which could have told you here why `===` couldn't work).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - its now working with `==`, I'll tick your answer when the time is up.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are again opening/closing your php brackets?

Just do it like this and see if it works

```
<?php 
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {                     
   if($_REQUEST['user_birth_day'] == $i) { 
     echo 'BINGO'; 
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: It was just for testing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['user_birth_day']; ?> // this outputs 5

<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) : ?>                     
    <?php if($_REQUEST['user_birth_day'] == $i){ echo 'BINGO'; } ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

and try once may be it works

Answer (score 0):

First store $_REQUEST['user_birth_day'] in some variable and try comparing them.

`$day = $_REQUEST['user_birth_day']`

```
if($day === $i)
{ 
echo 'BINGO'; 
}
```